# Apache Nutch - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, apache, nutch, nosuchmethoderror

I have installed Apache Nutch on Windows and I am trying to get it to run a simple crawl but I have the following error:

```
$ bin/crawl urls crawled 3
Injecting seed URLs
/cygdrive/c/Users/Simon/OneDrive/apache-nutch-1.11-bin/apache-nutch-1.11/bin/nutch inject crawled/crawldb urls
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder.withArgPattern(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder;
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.buildGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:59)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
Error running:
  /cygdrive/c/Users/Simon/OneDrive/apache-nutch-1.11-bin/apache-nutch-1.11/bin/nutch inject crawled/crawldb urls
Failed with exit value 1.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am going to guess that you have a rogue classpath entry. You should see what the value of your CLASSPATH environment variable is.

Comment: The JAVA_HOME  environment variable is set to D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 which appears to be correct . I don't have a CLASSPATH variable but there is a PATH environment variable ( not sure if they're the same) -  but I did not make any changes to this when installing Nutch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by installing an earlier version of Nutch (1.4) . The problem was with some of the newer versions of hadoop not working correctly in windows.

Comment: sidenote: switched to ubuntu setup and saved a lot of future wasted time :D